# help to understand some present simple examples

Tags: tense, present-tense

These examples i am taking from a grammar book. I want to know why we use past particle from in this instead verb first foam and also mention which type of sentences is it.

1)the garden is filled with men, women and children in the evening.
2)New York is the busiest city in USA. it is always crowded with people.

Answer (score 1):

The word "crowded" is used in your example as an "attributive verb," not as the past participle of the verb "to crowd." (NOTE: it is important to understand the difference between a "particle" and a "participle.")

Any verb has an "attributive" form which can be used as a modifier; "filled" and "crowded" are examples of this usage. This is clearly explained in your copy of Murphy's Grammar.